# Android Application with Login

Tags: android, authentication

I'm a French Computer Science Student.
I've a project to do, create a simple application for login into my website, display (if login is correct) a New activity with 3 tab (each tab contains an activity).
The application will be structured like this:
First Activity: Login.
If it is correct, go to the 3 tab activity.
First tab displayed is My Profile Tab, with My nickname and my stats (obtained with the API of my website).
The second tab is my friend tab.
The third is "Upload" tab.
I use it for upload photo that i taken in my photogallery.

Can someone follow and teach me about the creation of that app?
I need to know, for first thing, how to do login and keep the session to the tab activity, if the login is correct.

I see a lot of answers here on stackoverflow, but neither help me.
I see other questions from another guy, Phil, but the reply don't help me.

I hope you can give me an help.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tutorials, you should be able to get started with this forum.
[Android tutorial with source code](http://www.anddev.org/android-tutorials-with-source-code-f39/)

Build your app by taking bits of info that you need from each tutorial.